# Is it possible to check a cell to see if it has a formula in it - NOT looking for the value, without using vba

Tags: excel

So, I am looking to test the contents of a cell ie check if the cell is using "sum()" or "average()" or "frequency()" but not checking for the numerical result - that I can do and have achieved.

I have tried:

```
=CELL("type",C10)
```

cell C10 contains a frequency() function with a result of 10, so the cel() function gives a result of "v" as in value.
Also used "contents" and "format" in the cell function...

So, I have a feeling this is going to be vba...

Comment: What Excel are you using? Cause from Excel 2013 onwards you can use `=ISFORMULA()` function.

Comment: @JdV magic, can't believe I did not look there... post an answer or should I delete such a simple question?

Comment: It's up to you ofcourse. But accepting such an answer gives me a feeling of purpose haha! Enjoy the weekend 

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From Excel 2013 onwards you can use the build-in function: `=ISFORMULA()`

Comment: Magic, does exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the formula `=FORMULATEXT()`. In case thise gives `#N/A`, you don't have a formula (check using `IsNA()`).

Comment: Gave this a vote because it will work, but for what I wanted it becomes longer, tthanks anyway.